# Advice on classifying users in machine learning scenario

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, user-input

I'm looking for some advice in the problem of classifying users into various groups based on there answers to a sign up process.

The idea is that these classifications will group people with similar travel habits, i.e. adventurous, relaxing, foodie etc. This shouldn't be a classification known to the user, so isn't as simple as just asking what sort of holidays they like ( The point is to remove user bias/not really knowing where to place yourself).

The way I see it working is asking questions such as apps they use, accounts they interact with on social media (gopro, restaurants etc) , giving some scenarios and asking which sounds best, these would be chosen from a set provided to them, hence we have control over the variables. The main problem I have is how to get numerical values associated to each of these.

I've looked into various Machine learning algorithms and have realised this is most likely a clustering problem but I cant seem to figure out how to use this style of question to assign a value to each dimension that will actually give a useful categorisation.

Another question I have is whether there is some resources where I could find information on the sort of questions to ask users to gain information that'd allow classification like this.

The sort of process I envision is one similar to https://www.thread.com/signup/introduction if anyone is familiar with it.

Any advice welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have at hand is that you want to calculate a similarity measure based on categorical variables, which is the choice of their apps, accounts etc. Unless you measure the similarity of these apps with respect to an attribute such as how foodie is the app, it would be a hard problem to specify. Also, you would need to know all the possible states a categorical variable can assume to create a similarity measure like this. 
If the final objective is to recommend something that similar people (based on app selection or social media account selection) have liked or enjoyed, you should look into collaborative filtering.
If your feature space is well defined and static (known apps, known accounts, limited set with few missing values) then look into content based recommendation systems, something as simple as Market Basket  Analysis can give you a reasonable working model.
Else if you really want to model the system with a bunch of features that can assume random states, this could be done with multivariate probabilistic models, if the structure (relationships and influences between features) is well defined, you could benefit from Probabilistic Graphical Models, such as Bayesian Networks.
You really do need to define your problem better before you start solving it though.

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned the apps/accounts etc would be from a given set, so I'll have a look into the Market Basket Analysis

Answer (score 0):

You can use prime numbers. If each choice on the list of all possible choices is assigned a different prime, and the user's selection is saved as a product, then you will always know if the user has made a particular choice if the modulo of selection/choice is 0. Beauty of prime numbers, voila!

Comment: Thats really clever, thanks! How could I then use that to create the model though, if it isnt 'strict' with the choices made to determine like a decision tree, but more that multiple routes can give the same classification?